# Unable to create an envelope using DocuSign, API PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope created from a template in my account. But, I'm always getting the response:

HTTP Unauthorized 401
`{"errorCode":"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."}`

Here is my code:

```
from docusign_esign import TemplateRole, EnvelopesApi, RecipientViewRequest, EnvelopeDefinition, ApiClient


def create_api_client(base_path, access_token):
    """Create api client and construct API headers"""
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = base_path
    api_client.set_default_header(header_name="Authorization", header_value=f"Bearer {access_token}")

    return api_client


class Eg001Controller:
    @staticmethod
    def get_args():
        """Get request and session arguments"""
        # More data validation would be a good idea here
        # Strip anything other than characters listed
        # 1. Parse request arguments
        signer_email = "my@email.com"
        signer_name = "Some Random Guy"
        envelope_args = {
            "signer_email": signer_email,
            "signer_name": signer_name,
            "signer_client_id": "SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE",
            "ds_return_url": "http://localhost:5000/ds/callback",
        }
        args = {
            "account_id": {"API_CLIENT_ID"},  # My "API Account ID"
            "base_path": "demo.docusign.net/restapi",
            "access_token": "{ACCESS_TOKEN_GENERATED_BY_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_LAUNCHER}",
            "envelope_args": envelope_args
        }
        return args

    @classmethod
    def worker(cls, args):
        """
        1. Create the envelope request object
        2. Send the envelope
        3. Create the Recipient View request object
        4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the embedded signing
        """
        envelope_args = args["envelope_args"]
        # 1. Create the envelope request object
        envelope_definition = cls.make_envelope(envelope_args)

        # 2. call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        print("creating client..")
        api_client = create_api_client(base_path=args["base_path"], access_token=args["access_token"])

        print("creating envelope..")
        envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
        # It fails in the next line!
        results = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id=args["account_id"], envelope_definition=envelope_definition)

        envelope_id = results.envelope_id
        print(f"Created envelope ID: {envelope_id}")

        # 3. Create the Recipient View request object
        recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
            authentication_method="None",
            client_user_id=envelope_args["signer_client_id"],
            recipient_id="1",
            return_url=envelope_args["ds_return_url"],
            user_name=envelope_args["signer_name"],
            email=envelope_args["signer_email"]
        )
        # 4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the embedded signing
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        results = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(
            account_id=args["account_id"],
            envelope_id=envelope_id,
            recipient_view_request=recipient_view_request
        )

        return {"envelope_id": envelope_id, "redirect_url": results.url}

    @classmethod
    def make_envelope(cls, args):
        """
        Creates envelope
        args -- parameters for the envelope:
        signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
        returns an envelope definition
        """
        print("creating envelope definition..")
        # Create the envelope definition
        envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
            status="sent",  # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
            template_id="{TEMPLATE_ID}"
        )
        # Create template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
        # to the template
        signer = TemplateRole(
            email="my@email.com",
            name="Some Random Guy",
            role_name='Signer',
            client_user_id="SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE"
        )

        # Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
        envelope_definition.template_roles = [signer]
        return envelope_definition


Eg001Controller.worker(Eg001Controller.get_args())
```

Most of the code is duplicated from [this](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eg001_embedded_signing/controller.py) example.

Notes:

- I thought there might be a problem in generating the access token, so, I used the same token generated when I run their code launcher. There shouldn't be any problem with the token.
- I also get the same response if I generate the token manually with this code: (I'm using JWT auth)

```
    def jwt_auth():
        """JSON Web Token authorization"""
        api_client = ApiClient()
        api_client.set_base_path(BASE_PATH)
    
        # try:
        ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
            client_id=INTEGRATION_KEY,
            user_id=USER_ID,
            oauth_host_name=AUTH_SERVER,
            private_key_bytes=PRIVATE_KEY.encode("ascii").decode("utf-8"),
            expires_in=3600,  # Not configurable/extensible.
            scopes=SCOPES
        )
    
        return ds_app
```

- Their code launcher is able to complete embedded signing **successfully** with my account!
- When I add `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header that contains my account username & password, it works. But, certainly I want to be able to use just the token, not my login credentials!
- Why adding `X-DocuSign-Authentication` makes it work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            "base_path": "demo.docusign.net/restapi",
```

should instead be

```
            "base_path": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi",
```

I've filed DocuSign internal tickets to provide error checking for this parameter.